# Install chrome extension as external extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I need install chrome extension as a manual way. So I follow this page https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions. I install chrome extension with registry. Everything was fine. But the problem is: that extension cannot "remember anything". Each time I close and open chrome, it was installed again (extension show a welcome page) and everything it save from last session has gone. That problem does not exists if I install it as a normal way. So there are anyway to solve it?

Comment: Can you provide a reduced test case? More information is needed, such as code, and how you are persisting data.

Comment: That extension called "all manga reader" (not mime, just using it for testing). All extensions is normal if I install it as normal way.

Answer (score 7):

- Navigate to "chrome://extensions/" in the url bar...
- Click "Developer mode" in the top right hand corner.
- Click "Pack extension..."
- In the "Extension root directory" field, choose the **folder** that contains all your extension files.
- Leave the "Private key file" blank...
- Click OK

Your extension will now be packed into a .crx file wherever your parent extension directory was on your computer... there will also be a .pem file, which is irrelevant really, it just holds your private key in case you won't to update this same extension, in which case you would pack the extension with the private key file...

Open the .crx in chrome... It will give you a message saying extensions and themes may harm your computer... click OK, this message only shows up because the extension has not been tested by google in the extension gallery... Your extension will install and will remember all your data

Comment: You can no longer open the .crx file by browsing to it in Chrome.  You will need to download the extension and drag it onto the Tools|Extensions page.  See http://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2664769&p=crx_warning for the official explanation.