# install chrome extension outside the chrome extension market

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

As I know you can install an extension outside the market without expected limitations, for example, autoupdate. You need to be in develop mode.

You can read this thread to understand the problem:
[Install chrome extension as external extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208408/install-chrome-extension-as-external-extensions)

The think is, anyone know another way to install an extension in your chrome (internal use in a company o class). I like to think that I can sign the extension with a shared certificate or something like that. And send the extension to the users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google no longer allows it.

[Protecting Chrome users from malicious extensions](http://chrome.blogspot.ch/2014/05/protecting-chrome-users-from-malicious.html)
[Continuing to protect Chrome users from malicious extensions](http://blog.chromium.org/2015/05/continuing-to-protect-chrome-users-from.html)

There are 4 types of extension install still available:

- Direct installation from Webstore or [inline install](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/188453) from a website, but hosted on Web Store.
- Indirect installation through registry manipulation (e.g. companion extension for a native app), but it still must be hosted in the Webstore.
- Local development installs; will nag on every Chrome restart and no autoupdate mechanism.
- For Enterprise only, [policy-based installs](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/188453). Note that on Windows that requires computers joined to a domain. In this case there are no restrictions on where the extension is hosted.

Comment: Many Thanks!! 
and installing the app manually, any chance to have autoupdate? Thats my main problem.

Comment: No; however, please note that there are publishing options in CWS that limit exposure of your extension. You can publish to trusted testers or unlisted.

Comment: I didn;t know that. I will look into it!!

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033335/private-beta-testing-a-chrome-extension/23033717#23033717

Comment: or use another OS ;)